# Convert json string into json object?

Tags: jquery

I have the following json string:

```
{"nick":"person1", "text":"hello "}
```

I want to convert it into a object to access each variable.

I've tried the following:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(text);
alert(obj.nick);
```

Where text is the json string.

This gives and error "Illegal character".

However, if i copy and paste the string itself and insert it into the parseJSON function it works..

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: What you have is already an object. No need to parse it. Like @mimipc said, you need quotes to make it a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var object = {"nick":"person1", "text":"hello "};
console.log(object.nick);
```

Comment: for some reason this does not work, ive used console.log(text) and this is what i get: {"nick":"person1", "text":"hello
"} but when i do console.log(text.nick) i get "unidentified"

Comment: are u using like this '{"nick":"person1", "text":"hello "}', if so remove quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you put quotes around your var value ?

```
var text = '{"nick":"person1", "text":"hello "}';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  var text = '{"nick":"person1", "text":"hello "}';
  var obj = $.parseJSON(text);
  alert(obj.nick);
```

this is simple json:

```
 {"nick":"person1", "text":"hello "}
```

to make it string wrap it with single quotes:

```
'{"nick":"person1", "text":"hello "}'
```